# How redirect packets UDP ASSOCIATE via socks5

Tags: vpn, tcpclient, socks, udpclient, httptosocks5proxy

TCP can redirect but UDP not working, Please help.

TCP get from ip:port destination
UDP get from ip:port endpoit